# Use of collections in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am creating nodejs project that monitors prices from a local supermarket. So far I've managed to download all of them. Each product will have an object that looks something like this:

```
{
  id: 37982,
  name: carrots,
  link: /product/carrots,
  price: 7,
  date: 2020-12-13
}
```

The idea is just to monitor the prices for all products daily and if a product changes price, then save it to the database.

But what's the intended use of mongodb with regards to collections? There are 20.000 products in total. Should I make a collection for each product? Or should I have a single Product collection where all price changes are stored?

There are probably price changes at most once a week and only on a subset of the products.

Comment: The idea is to keep the price history for each product

Comment: A "collection" corresponds to a "table" in relational SQL databases, so it would be definitely a bad idea to store each item in a collection. Maybe have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/index.html